# Queue sorting function

Tags: c, data-structures, arduino, queue

I want to sort a queue of strings.

Only functions in my arsenel are:

```
queue.count() - returns size
queue.pop() - return head, delete head
queue.push(String str) - add string at head
queue.get(int index) - return value stored at index

queue object - original strings stored in here
temp object - sorted strings should go here
temp1 object - temporary queue for help with sorting
```

I have initialized the queue like this:

```
String a[] = {"First", "third", "second"};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    queue.push(a[i]);
```

I have tried and written this code:

```
 temp.push(queue.peek());

  for (int i = 0; i < queue.count(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < temp.count(); j++)
    {
      if (temp.get(j) != queue.get(i))
      {
        if (temp.get(j) > queue.get(i))
        {
          temp.push(queue.get(i));
        }
        else
        {
          for (int k = 0; k < temp.count(); k++)
            temp1.push(temp.pop());

          temp.push(queue.get(i));

          for (int k = 0; k < temp1.count(); k++)
            temp.push(temp1.pop());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It should return:

first

second

third

But it returns:

first

second

third

third

second

Comment: If you want a sorted "queue" then you are looking at the wrong data-structure. Queues are inheritly not sorted, they are first in first out. A sorted queue is an oxymoron.

Comment: I want to sort it :P no other option available. Please help

Comment: Queue of strings :P

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what the *actual* problem is we might be able to help you better? What is the problem that causes you tu attempt to stort a data-structure that can't be sorted? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), it's very relevant in regards to your question.

Comment: how do you store "strings"?

Comment: My problem is very simple. But due to lack of time I am forced to take this avenue.

I want to read strings from an arduino serial monitor. sort them, and then display them back.

Arduino which runs in C. Due to lack of time, instead of writing whole data structure coding, I picked a `QueueList` library for arduino available on internet. I can't seem to find a suitable library for any other data structure.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath See code. edited it

Comment: @MohsinAnees You might be interested in [this project](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus), then you can use standard C++ classes like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and algorithm functions like [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). That will simplify your life quite a bit I think. :)

Comment: Why is there a C tag? Looks more like C++ to me.

Comment: Can't you just allocate an array of strings (pointers) that's the same size as the queue? Then call `pop` repeatedly to get the strings into the array, and sort the array using the built-in `qsort` function, or with your own custom sorting function. I don't see anything in your question indicating why you can't take that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that this is an exercise in creative thinking, rather than a real-world problem. Although something like this might have been a real-world problem back in the day of tape drives and limited memory.

If all you can do is use the queue's `pop` and `push` methods, then you can do what is essentially a really inefficient bubble sort. This requires O(n^2) operations and O(1) extra space.

Pseudocode:

```
size = queue.Count

for i = 0 to size-1
    largest = queue.pop()
    for j = 1 to size-1
        temp = queue.pop()
        if temp > largest
            queue.push(largest)
            largest = temp
        else
            queue.push(temp)
        end if
    end for
    queue.push(largest)
end for
```

So the first time through the loop, it makes sure that the largest item is at the end of the queue. The next time through, it will put the second-largest in its place, etc.

There are some minor optimizations possible, but they don't affect the running time very much because you still have to pop and push every item every time through the loop.

There is a possible early-out, just like there is for bubble sort. If in every iteration of the inner loop, `temp > largest`, then you know the queue is in order. That could be a useful optimization, and it's not hard to implement:

```
size = queue.Count
isInOrder = false
while isInOrder == false
    isInOrder = true
    largest = queue.pop()
    for j = 1 to size-1
        temp = queue.pop()
        if temp > largest
            queue.push(largest)
            largest = temp
        else
            queue.push(temp)
            isInOrder = false
        end if
    end for
    queue.push(largest)
end while
```

Given that you can also call the queue's `get` method, there's probably a faster way to do this. Still O(n^2) complexity, but real-world running time could potentially be better. I'd have to think on that one.